# Import json file to object error

Tags: ios, swift, decodable

I have this json file:
http://serwer1356363.home.pl/pub/json.txt

and this code:

```
var ProductsObjectArray = [Products]()
let data = try Data(contentsOf: path)
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let ProductsObjectArray = try decoder.decode(Products.self, from: data)
```

And model:

```
struct ProductObject : Codable {
    let palletHeight : Double?
    let layerPallet : Int?
    let prepCombisteamer : String?
    let id : Int?
    let prepOven : String?
}
```

When I start this code I get an error:

> Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary,
>   Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription:
>   "Expected to decode Dictionary but found an array
>   instead.", underlyingError: nil))

I would like to write json to the Products Object Array object array.
How can someone repair it?

Comment: What is `Products` in the `try decoder.decode(Products.self, from: data)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assuming that `ProductObject` implemented as it should and you are reading the data from the file appropriately:*

As mentioned in the error:

> "Expected to decode Dictionary but found an array instead."

the json file contains an *array* of `ProductObject`, it seems that there is a `Products` in your code, which should *not* be used for the decoder, probably you should decode it like this:

```
let ProductsObjectArray = try decoder.decode([ProductObject].self, from: data)
```

which means that `ProductsObjectArray` would be an array of `ProductObject`. Nothing to do with dictionaries.

---

*Aside bar tip*: when it comes to naming variables, you should follow the *lower camel case* convention instead of the upper camel case one:

`ProductsObjectArray` → `productsObjectArray`

`ProductsObjectArray` → `productsObjectArray`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to parse a `Dictionary` model when the JSON is an `Array`

Change

```
let ProductsObjectArray = try decoder.decode(Products.self, from: data)
```

to

```
let ProductsObjectArray = try decoder.decode([Products].self, from: data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON contains a list of products at the top level so you need to be decoding an Array of products rather than a single dictionary.

try replacing

```
let ProductsObjectArray = try decoder.decode(Products.self, from: data)
```

with

```
let ProductsObjectArray = try decoder.decode([Products].self, from: data)
```

Comment: Hey! it seems that being it as an array is *not* only the issue ;)

Comment: yeah, Good spot!